# Groovy Inner Classes wont work with Apache Wicket

Tags: groovy, wicket, wicket-6

Im trying to write simple things with Apache Wicket (6.15.0) and Groovy (2.2.2 or 2.3.1). And Im having trouble with inner classes.

```
class CreatePaymentPanel extends Panel { 
  public CreatePaymentPanel(String id) {
    super(id)
    add(new PaymentSelectFragment('currentPanel').setOutputMarkupId(true))
}

public class PaymentSelectFragment extends Fragment {
        public PaymentSelectFragment(String id) {
            super(id, 'selectFragment', CreatePaymentPanel.this) // problem here
            add(new AjaxLink('cardButton') {
                @Override
                void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    ... CreatePaymentPanel.this // not accessible here 
                }
            })
            add(new AjaxLink('terminalButton') {
                @Override
                void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    ... CreatePaymentPanel.this // not accessible here 
                }
            });
        }
        } // end of PaymentSelectFragment class
} // end of CreatePaymentPanel class
```

Groovy tries to find a property "this" in CreatePaymentPanel class.. How to workaround this? It is a valid java code, but not groovy.

However,
Test.groovy:

```
class Test {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def a = new A()
    }

    static class A {
        A() {
            def c = new C()
        }

        public void sayA() { println 'saying A' }

        class B {
            public B(A instance) {
                A.this.sayA()
                instance.sayA()
            }
        }
        /**
         * The problem occurs here
         */
        class C extends B {
            public C() {
                super(A.this) // groovy tries to find property "this" in A class
                sayA()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code wont work, the same error occurs, like in Wicket's case.

And TestJava.java, the same and working:

```
public class TestJava {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }

    static class A {
        A() {
            C c = new C();
        }

        public void sayA() {
            System.out.println("saying A");
        }

        class B {
            public B(A instance) {
                instance.sayA();
            }
        }

        /**
         * This works fine
         */
        class C extends B {
            public C() {
                super(A.this);
                sayA();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I'm having a different error when try to run you Test.groovy `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/test/A$C, method: <init> signature: (Lcom/test/A;)V) Expecting to find object/array on stack`.
It may be a bug. Groovy 2.2.0

Comment: I have the same error, while the same java code works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to a `CreatePaymentPanel.this` inside of `PaymentSelectFragment` because there is no instance of `CreatePamentPanel` that would be accessible there.  What would you expect that to evaluate to if it were allowed?

Comment: what am I missing? My expectations works fine with Java code, while groovy does not. And no, there is instance of CreatePaymentPanel because new PaymentSelectFragment instantiated inside CreatePaymentPanel and CreatePaymentPanel.this should be accessable as it is super class instance. Am I right?

Comment: No, I don't think you are right.  I don't think there is an instance of CreatePaymentPanel which is implicitly associated with any instance of PaymentSelectFragment.  Just because you create an instance of PaymentSelectFragment from an instance of CreatePaymentPanel doesn't mean that there will be any relationship between those instances that allows you to do this sort of thing.  That is true of Java as well.

Comment: Ok, but in Java it works.. Also please take a look at Test.groovy, if you will use A.this not in super(A.this); just remove it, and write A.this.sayA() instead of super(A.this) and it will work fine. It works fine while A.this is not in super constructor block..

Comment: You formatted your sample code such that it wasn't clear that PaymentSelectFragment was defined inside of CreatePaymentPanel.  At a glance it looked like they were both top level classes.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes it wasn't clear. Also there is another bug i found. How can I contact you to create an issue?

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, you are right.  I was mistaken because of the formatting of the code.  I misread the nesting of the classes in the sample code.  Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: You don't have to contact me to create an issue.  Our JIRA is open to the public.  Visit http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY.